# Hide "Create new subsite" in SharePoint site

Tags: sharepoint-server

I wanted to hide the link `new subsite`, available in `viewlsts.aspx` for all users in few SharePoint sites.

Is there any way to hide this link?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a script to hide the "New subsite" link in masterpage. You can find the id of the tag with Web tools in firefox. Mine is id="createnewsite" So yours have to be it too. You have to add the fllowing code under PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead.

```
<style type="text/css">
#createnewsite{
 display:none;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Can this be done using Powershell code?

Comment: I have no idea but i dont think so.